# Setting media type ignored on output pin

Tags: c++, winapi, video, directshow

I'm building a DirectShow graph.
I have video capture filter that connects its output pin to the input pin of SampleGrabber.
Before I connect two pins, I configure output pin like this:

```
HRESULT GraphBuilder::applyVideoFormat()
{
    if( !pVideoCaptureFilter_ )
        return E_FAIL;

    CComPtr<IPin> pPin;
    pPin.Attach( findCategoryPin( pVideoCaptureFilter_, PINDIR_OUTPUT, PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE ) );

    if( !pPin )
        return E_FAIL;

    CComQIPtr<IAMStreamConfig> pConfig( pPin );

    if( !pConfig )
        return E_FAIL;

    AM_MEDIA_TYPE   mt = { 0 };
    VIDEOINFOHEADER vih = { 0 };

    if( videoStandard_ == AnalogVideo_NTSC_M )
        vih.AvgTimePerFrame         = 333667;
    else
        vih.AvgTimePerFrame         = 400000;

    vih.bmiHeader.biSize            = sizeof( BITMAPINFOHEADER );
    vih.bmiHeader.biWidth           = captureResolution_.cx;
    vih.bmiHeader.biHeight          = captureResolution_.cy;
    vih.bmiHeader.biPlanes          = 1;
    vih.bmiHeader.biBitCount        = 16;
    vih.bmiHeader.biCompression     = mmioFOURCC('Y','U','Y','2');
    vih.bmiHeader.biSizeImage       = vih.bmiHeader.biWidth * vih.bmiHeader.biHeight * 2;

    mt.majortype                    = MEDIATYPE_Video;
    mt.subtype                      = MEDIASUBTYPE_YUY2;
    mt.bFixedSizeSamples            = TRUE;
    mt.bTemporalCompression         = FALSE;
    mt.lSampleSize                  = vih.bmiHeader.biSizeImage;
    mt.formattype                   = FORMAT_VideoInfo;
    mt.cbFormat                     = sizeof( VIDEOINFOHEADER );
    mt.pbFormat                     = (BYTE*)&vih;
    mt.pUnk                         = NULL;

    return pConfig->SetFormat( &mt ); // SUCCESS - always
}
```

I also configure the sample grabber, although I know it will consider only the major type and subtype. It doesn't care about the rest.

```
HRESULT GraphBuilder::configureVideoSampleGrabber( ISampleGrabber * const pSampleGrabber )
{
    AM_MEDIA_TYPE mt = { 0 };
    VIDEOINFOHEADER vih = { 0 };

    if( videoStandard_ == AnalogVideo_NTSC_M )
        vih.AvgTimePerFrame         = 333667;
    else
        vih.AvgTimePerFrame         = 400000;

    vih.bmiHeader.biSize            = sizeof( BITMAPINFOHEADER );
    vih.bmiHeader.biWidth           = captureResolution_.cx;
    vih.bmiHeader.biHeight          = captureResolution_.cy;
    vih.bmiHeader.biPlanes          = 1;
    vih.bmiHeader.biBitCount        = 16;
    vih.bmiHeader.biCompression     = mmioFOURCC('Y','U','Y','2');
    vih.bmiHeader.biSizeImage       = vih.bmiHeader.biWidth * vih.bmiHeader.biHeight * 2;

    mt.majortype                    = MEDIATYPE_Video;
    mt.subtype                      = MEDIASUBTYPE_YUY2;
    mt.bFixedSizeSamples            = TRUE;
    mt.bTemporalCompression         = FALSE;
    mt.lSampleSize                  = vih.bmiHeader.biSizeImage;
    mt.formattype                   = FORMAT_VideoInfo;
    mt.cbFormat                     = sizeof( VIDEOINFOHEADER );
    mt.pbFormat                     = (BYTE*)&vih;
    mt.pUnk                         = NULL;

    return pSampleGrabber->SetMediaType( &mt ); // SUCCESS - always
}
```

This code is called once the filters are in the graph, but BEFORE they are connected. All return values are 0.
In this example, the captureResolution_.cx = 352 and captureResolution_.cy = 240.
Now, the question is: **WHY do I get the default 720x480 always through the SampleGrabber instead of 352x240?? I configured the capture pin to deliver 352x240.**

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is about right, there are however a few things you want to change.

You definitely want to review your Sample Grabber initialization. You don't need a fully specified media type set on it. Instead you want a partial media type with only major type an subtype initialized (and the rest is `NULL`'ed). The rationale is the following.

Sample Grabber is just an inset which you configure to insist on specific media type. In particular, it is unable to work out a connection type on the upstream connection in any other way than straightforwardly compare attempts to its internal reference type and accept or reject depending on result of this comparison. Having said this, your Sample Grabber cannot help setting the resolution, but it can reject the connection if media type is different in some unimportant field. It is sufficient to require video, YUY2 on Sample Grabber, and the rest of the format is the responsibility of video source.

To make sure this media type is okay for the video source you can always connect it interactively without Sample Grabber and review all fields of effective connection media type.

Comment: I know all that. That's why I wrote "it (smplGrabber) will consider only the major type and subtype". That's expected, but shouldn't the output pin try to use the previously set format during the next connect attempt? I believe it should and sample grabber should simply check the major type and subtype (color format). Since it's a match, the resolution should be 352x240. Or am I missing something? I mean, I can write my own version of sample grabber, but there is no point, because I want that filter to accept any resolution in the desired color format. And sample grabber is doing exactly that.

Comment: Once they were unable to connect directly, follow up attempts are possible and expected, at discretion of source filter and then depending on filters participating in Intelligent Connect. There might be another filter switching (incl. incorrectly) to 352x240 and/or the source filter accepts your format and then attempt to connect using interlaced video format (which SG rejects) or VIH2 block. I don't think there is an answer to your question in the provided information. It's clear they cannot agree on primary connection type, to see why exactly you need to know what media types are tried.

Comment: I can tell you for sure there are no other filters required for setting the resolution. I add all filters manually and I'm connecting pins manually. Once the resolution is set on the output pin (capture filter), it will use this format for its next connection. It's plain and simple. Since the grabber checks only major type and subtype, it cannot reject this connect attempt. The problem is in output pin, so I do not want to walk away in the wrong direction searching for the solution. I believe there is an answer, but we don't know it yet.

Comment: `1` `IGraphBuilder::Connect` might add filters you don't expect, and `2` before connecting output pin you might want to enumerate media types on the output pin to make sure you see what you expect here. The first media type is typically use to make a connection attempt. If it's not accepted by SG, then SG rejects it for some reason, and esp. because it is different from what you are setting (interlacing or VIH2 format type - the typical reasons).

Comment: `1` I do not use IGraphBuilder::Connect because it can add filters. I'll repeat one more time "I add and connect filters manually", `I do not use IGraphBuilder::Connect`. `2` The output pin supports media type that I set. `3` I have never had problems with SG and interlaced video and that is not the problem, because hardware deinterlacing is enabled. `4` It is always `FORMAT_VideoInfo`, never `FORMAT_VideoInfo2`. I mean, in this particular case.

Comment: OK, I was really, really dumb. I was looking at the preview pin data all the time. The capture pin delivers what it's been told to deliver. Feel free to call me stupid and kick me (double facepalm).

Comment: Nevermind, you seem to be on top of everything, it was just some small thing you were missing.